# Generator has 4 prongs, can an adapter be used?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, generator

I bought a generator that has the power cord with 4 prongs on the end. Can I use a three prong adapter to plug into the regular house electrical or do I need an electrician to install a box that accepts a 4 prong?

Comment: Please revise to provide more detail. We have virtually nothing to work with here, and this is potentially a deadly situation.

Comment: Can you provide us with photos of your electrical panel(s) please as well as the make and model of your generator?

Comment: "Prongs" on electrical connectors come in various sizes, shapes, and arrangements.  A picture is required to understand your situation.

Comment: Yes, you need to hire an electrician.

Comment: You need to START with a competent generator interlock, which interlocks the main breaker with a back-fed breaker so both can't be on at once.  Then you wire that to an inlet (socket with prongs).  Then you use a normal generator extension cord. **NEVER use a "suicide cord" with prongs on both ends of it!**  Not only can that kill the linemen working to restore your power, it can kill your family.  Sorry to yell, but it sounds like you were trying to do a cheap-and-lazy backfeed, and those are so dangerous the yelling is called for.

Comment: I wouldn't say "hire an electrician"... ANYONE can do it right... but it needs to be done right, one way or the other.  We're here to help.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot just use an adapter and hook your generator up to your house electrical panel. You need a transfer switch to isolate your service from the power company when your generator is in use. Installing one can be pretty complicated and permits are usually involved. Unless you are very knowledgeable about what's involved, getting professional help would be advisable.

Answer (score 5):

There are a whole bunch of important safety issues here.

But the two key items - that **must** be followed:

1. 3-prong vs. 4-prong: While there are some exceptions (the issue of old 3-prong dryer receptacles vs. new 4-prong), typically that is the difference between 120V (hot/neutral/ground) and 240V (hot/hot/neutral/ground). That is a **big** difference. If you managed to get your 4-prong generator connected to a typical 3-prong home receptacle, you would end up with a **lot** of problems + things most likely not working.
2. Inlet vs. Outlet and Transfer: While it may seem like it shouldn't matter - if the power is out then what's wrong with adding power to your house from a generator - the proper way to get power from a generator to your house (short of a permanent hardwired installation) is with an **inlet**. This effectively makes it so you don't have live **dangerous** prongs from a cord sticking out of your cable (either end, depending on the situation). Plus a **transfer switch** (which can take many forms - a purpose-built transfer switch, interlock + subpanel, etc.) prevents you from backfeeeding your generator power into the utility lines and zapping (potentially fatally) the people who are trying to restore the utility power.

Speaking of backfeeding - I just discovered [this fantastic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xoyb9M5-EA) showing many of the dangers involved with electrical work. It is (as you'll see) primarily targeted to fire & rescue personnel but really includes a lot of useful information and warnings for everyone. About 19:45 it gets to a demonstration of how a small generator can backfeed to produce dangerously high voltage on power lines.

Bottom line: This is often (not always) a job for an electrician, and in any case needs to be done carefully, thoughtfully and safely.